# how to achieve env variable substitution in docker run & use one variable relatively in remaining env variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

please suggest how I can define one env variable and refer it relatively across other env variables. I understand there is `ARG & ENV` approach in `docker-compose`. However, how can I achieve it using `docker run`. Or do I have to declare it explicitly in every env variable ? I tried googling but no luck. All approaches are pointing towards dockerfile.

Example:

```
cloud_user@vijaygharge1c:~/Downloads$ docker run -itd --rm -e ELK_VERSION=7.8.0 -e ES_VERSION="${ELK_VERSION}"  --name "test" phusion/baseimage:18.04-1.0.0
2cd77b32f1b4336b18d7b5e0b342c37a2110832264d545d02668fe2b365ae2ae
cloud_user@vijaygharge1c:~/Downloads$ docker exec test env | grep VERSION
ELK_VERSION=7.8.0
ES_VERSION=
cloud_user@vijaygharge1c:~/Downloads$ 
cloud_user@vijaygharge1c:~/Downloads$ docker -v
Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe
cloud_user@vijaygharge1c:~/Downloads$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ES_VERSION is not defined previously, it's not possible what you're trying.

It's possible if you previously define:

```
export ELK_VERSION=7.8.0
docker run -itd --rm -e ELK_VERSION=${ELK_VERSION} -e ES_VERSION="${ELK_VERSION}"  --name "test" phusion/baseimage:18.04-1.0.0
```

Another possibility is define ELK_VERSION in .env for your docker-compose.yml.

Comment: So stupid of me. It's simple bash variable substitution that I was trying to achieve which has nothing to do with docker. Thanks again for this.